# How Will I know for how long a cell is visible in a collection view Swift 5

Tags: swift

I want to call a method when a cell is atleast 50% visible for atleast 1 second.

Here I am using -

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        startTimer()
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplaying cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        stopTimer()
    }
```

I am having atleast 2 to 3 cells depending on the height of cells.

My question - How can I keep a track of the timer for each cell before it is disappear .

Thanks in advance